# problem writing in file

Tags: c, fopen

```
FILE *ExcelFile = fopen("testdata.csv","w");
if (ExcelFile == NULL)
    return -1;
fprintf(ExcelFile,"1 2 3");

fprintf(ExcelFile,"\n");
fclose(ExcelFile);

//==============================================
FILE *fa = fopen("testdata.csv","w");
if (fa == NULL)
    return -1;
fseek (fa, 6 , SEEK_SET );
fprintf(ExcelFile,"a");


fclose(fa);
```

in the code i have write 1 2 3 in the file and also inserted '\n' (required for the program) now i want to place a after 3 like 1 2 3 a but hte problem iam facing is that my code erase all char an simply write a . help required .thanks

Comment: Edited for code formatting.  If you put four spaces before each line of code, that triggers code formatting, and it'll be a lot more readable.

Comment: You are using fa and ExcelFile, in the second part.  Is this a typo?  Please cut and paste a minimal but complete example of your problem.

Comment: @randy At StackOverflow, we are happy to help you with your questions! When you "accept an answer" by pressing the greencheckmark next to the answer that you feel was the solution, it shows us that you appreciate and acknowledge the help given. Like saying 'Thanks mate! Have a beer.', only, without actually buying the beer. : )

Comment: @Aprogrammer is talking about this : `FILE *fa = fopen(... fprintf(ExcelFile,"a"); `. Shouldn't this say `fprintf(fa,"a");` ?

Comment: ok rib.usa sir i got it i didnt know about greencheckmark now i will definitely press this thanks you people are awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want mode "r+".  Using mode "a", all writes will go to the end of the file.

Comment: @randy  Perhaps accepting the answer is a better response. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Every time you open your file, you are opening it as a 'w' option. In C, this has a specific meaning : start writing at the beginning of the file.

For your first write of the file, this is okay, but for every subsequent write, you're overwriting your previous content.

**Solution** Use the 'a' attribute instead here. Like this:

```
FILE *fa = fopen("testdata.csv","a");
```

[See more information about fopen here...](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/fopen.html)

**EDIT**

Reading your comments, I understand that when you write again, the next thing starts on a new line. This is because of your initial write `1 2 3 \n` (The `\n` makes a new line).

To correct this you can :

- Don't write a '\n' at all.
  ***OR***
- Read the entire file first, rewrite it without the `\n` and then write your new `a` and `\n`

Comment: i have also used this but it append at the end

Comment: @randy I revised my answer for you

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a CSV file should have "comma separated values", as the name indicates. So, rather than "1 2 3", you'd better have "1,2,3" or "1;2;3".

Now, there are multiple ways of opening a file : you're only using the "w" as "writing" mode. When you're in writing mode, you're erasing your file. You could use the "a" as "add" mode, which mean that everything will be put after it.

You could also :

1°) First read your file with a "r" mode and store it in memory. Then, close it.

2°) Then, open your file with a "w" mode, copy what you stored, and then make your addendum. Then, close it.

(There is a "reading and writing mode" too, check the link provided by another answer ; but this solution can easily be broken in small pieces, to have small functions doing each their part of the job).

Comment: but append mode append at the end in the next line

Comment: What do you mean ? If the problem is that it is "at the next line", get rid of the "\n" you added (5th line of the code in the question).

Comment: @rlb.usa : I had some pretty neat bugs with CSV recently, so I'm getting paranoid with this format :)

Answer (score 1):

You specified `w` for `fopen()`, which means "create the file or open for overwrite if already exists".

Therefore, your second call to `fopen()` cleared the file's contents.

Use `a`, for: "create the file, or append to it if already exists".

Comment: but append mode append at the end in the next line

Comment: Which is what you wanted: "now i want to place a after 3 like 1 2 3 a". By the way, the call to `fseek()` is superfluous, as the append mode place the cursor just at the end. UNLESS you want the "a" appearing after "3" but before the "\n". If you want to add to the **middle** of the file, or to delete contents from a file, you have to re-write it from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

fopen (filename,"a")

a = append

Comment: but append mode append at the end in the next line