# Program not working correctly

Tags: c

When I enter 10 in the input, the program comes out like this:

`Enter item number: 10`

`Enter unit price: Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yy): Item Unit Purchase`

`Price Date`

`10 $0.000 /32764/-572332368`

Do I have to create a txt file and enter the input values?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)

{

        int item_number, month, day, year;
        float unit_price;

        printf("Enter item number: ");
        scanf("%d", &item_number);

        printf("Enter unit price: ");
        scanf("$%f", &unit_price);

        printf("Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yy): ");
        scanf("d%/d%/d%", &month, &day, &year);

        printf("Item Unit Purchase\n");
        printf("Price Date\n");
        printf("%-d $%.2f%-02d/%02d/%02d\n", item_number, unit_price, month, day, year);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: What's with the `"d%"`?

Comment: @Ôrel please, tone it down a notch

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157333/problem-writing-in-file/5157380 shows how to open a file in different modes using fopen and writing to it using fprintf.

Comment: You should compile like this `gcc -g "yourfile.c"`  then debug line by line, that would help you to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the "$%f" to "%f", and "d%" to "%d", see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `scanf()` "worked".

Taking two of your scanfs as an example

```
if (scanf("$%f", &unit_price) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "scanf error at line %d.\n", __LINE__ - 1);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (scanf("d%/d%/d%", &month, &day, &year) != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "scanf error at line %d.\n", __LINE__ - 1);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the warnings you get. I would recommend you to go through these warning and it will help you to understand the problem:

```
warning: unknown conversion type character ‘/’ in format [-Wformat=]
         scanf("d%/d%/d%", &month, &day, &year);
               ^
:17:15: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘/’ in format [-Wformat=]
:17:15: warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]
:17:15: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
:21:16: warning: '0' flag ignored with '-' flag in gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]
         printf("%-d $%.2f%-02d/%02d/%02d\n", item_number, unit_price, month, da
```

---

You need to know the usage of STDIN an STDOUT `printf()` and `scanf()` [format specifier usage](https://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm). Go through this link it will help you.

**Just modified your code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {

        int item_number, month, day, year;
        float unit_price;

        printf("Enter item number: ");
        scanf("%d", &item_number);

        printf("Enter unit price: ");
        scanf("$%f", &unit_price);

        printf("Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yy): ");
        scanf("%d, %d, %d", &month, &day, &year);

        printf("Item Unit Purchase\n");
        printf("Price Date\n");
        printf("%d $:%.2f /%d/ %02d, %02d\n", item_number, unit_price, month, day, year);

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter item number: 10
Enter unit price: Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yy): 2/6/8
Item Unit Purchase
Price Date
10 $:0.00 /2/ 00, 1183423824
```